# How to get value of clicked button in calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, calculator, digits

I have multiple buttons containing different values

```
<button data-action="digit" class="button" id="1">1</button>
<button data-action="digit" class="button" id="2">2</button>
<button data-action="digit" class="button" id="3">3</button>
```

And I want to get these buttons to display on my calculator using this in javascript:

```
function digit_pressed(digit) {
    

    console.log("digit pressed: " + digit);
}
```

But I am unsure what to add to my function. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `querySelectorAll` for select all `button` then use `addEventListener` for add click event and last step use `textContent` for number of digit and call function.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(el =>{
  el.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    digit_pressed(el.textContent);
  });
});
function digit_pressed(digit) {
  console.log("digit pressed: " + digit);
}
```

```html
<button data-action="digit" class="button" id="1">1</button>
<button data-action="digit" class="button" id="2">2</button>
<button data-action="digit" class="button" id="3">3</button>
```

Reference:

- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll?retiredLocale=en)
- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: @Harry have you test my code?